# Looping through array of arrays... why won't this work?

Tags: javascript, createjs

I'd like to loop through data from two arrays to check if any of the data's distance is close to the player.

Container arrays (only 1 element in each right now):

```
peopleContainers_Array.push(peopleContainer);
animalContainers_Array.push(animalContainer);
```

I've loaded two arrays of create js `containers` into NPC_Array:

```
NPC_Array.push(peopleContainers_Array, animalContainers_Array);
```

And would like to loop through both as such to get the `x,y` values of data elements in the container arrays.

```
for (npc_array in NPC_Array) {
     //NPC_Array(peopleContainers_Array, animalContainers_Array);
    for (container in NPC_Array[npc_array]) {
        console.log(NPC_Array[npc_array[container].x]); //outputs undefined
    }
}
```

Why wouldn't this work?

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: You may want to read through "[Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (npc_array in NPC_Array) {
     //NPC_Array(peopleContainers_Array, animalContainers_Array);
    for (container in NPC_Array[npc_array]) {
        console.log(NPC_Array[npc_array][container].x);
    }
}
```

I think it should be like this.

**Well,replace `for ... in`:**

```
for (var index=0;index<NPC_Array.length;index++) {
     //NPC_Array(peopleContainers_Array, animalContainers_Array);
    for (var childIndex=0;childIndex<NPC_Array[index].length;childIndex++) {
        console.log(NPC_Array[index][childIndex]['x']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from using a `for...in` loop when a regular `for` loop, yes.

Comment: @MattBall What's wrong with using `for...in`? I want to get the objects within an array; isn't that what it's used for? Maybe I don't know the difference of when to use `for...in` vs `for`

Comment: @Growler [scroll up.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222519/looping-through-array-of-arrays-why-wont-this-work/18222548?noredirect=1#comment26712856_18222519)

Comment: @Growler `for...in` is used to iterate members of objects rather than array, if did it, unpredictable issues may come up.See the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) Jonathan Lonowski gave in the comment.